# Move non repeating numbers from 2 arrays in new array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I want the numbers in the first array that do not repeat with the numbers in the second array to go to the third array

This is what I have done till now and it doesn`t work...please help

```
for(int i = 0; i < isir.length; i++) 
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < isir2.length; j++) 
    {
        if(isir[i] != isir[j]) 
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < sirdif1.length; k++) 
            {
                sirdif1[k] = isir[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am entering the numbers from console with Scanner function...

Comment: As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

With using lists and steams:

```
    Integer a1[] = {1,2,5,6,8};
    Integer a2[] = {1,3,5,7,8};

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    // Add elements from first array which ist not in the second
    Arrays.stream(a1).filter(_a -> !Arrays.asList(a2).contains(_a)).forEach(result::add);
    // Add elements from second array which ist not in the first
    Arrays.stream(a2).filter(_a -> !Arrays.asList(a1).contains(_a)).forEach(result::add);
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output will be:
    2
    6
    3
    7

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use `Set`s for clarity.

```
public void test() {
    Integer[] a1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
    Integer[] a2 = {2,3,4};
    // Treat them as Sets.
    Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a1));
    Set<Integer> s2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a2));
    // Get the union of both.
    Set<Integer> all = new HashSet<>(s1);
    all.addAll(s2);
    // Find the repeating ones.
    Set<Integer> common = new HashSet<>(s1);
    common.retainAll(s2);
    // Non-repeating is.
    Set<Integer> nonRepeats = new HashSet<>(all);
    nonRepeats.removeAll(common);
    System.out.println(nonRepeats);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest good naming conventions first..variables like `sirdif1`(i cant even imagine how this name was decided..) really make it hard for others to read/help

```
int a1[] ; // Initialize array1
int a2[] ; // Initialize array2

List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < a2.length; i++)
{
    boolean found = false; // To be able to track if the int was found in both arrays
    for(int j = 0; j < a1.length; j++)
    {
        if(a1[j].equals(a2[i]))
        {
            found = true; 
            break; // If it exist in both arrays there is no need to look further
        }
    }
    if(!found ) // If the same is not found in both..
        tempList.add(a2[i]); // .. add to temporary list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Temporary array to combine both arrays;
int[] merged= new int[isir1.length + isir1.length];
//Copy isir1 into new temporary "merged" array;
System.arraycopy(isir1, 0, merged, 0, isir1.length);
//Copy isir2 into new temporary "merged" array;
System.arraycopy(isir2, 0, merged, isir1.length, isir2.length);

//Get the unique values of array "merged" and assign them to new array;
int[] sirdif1= IntStream.of(merged).distinct().toArray();
```